# Class that contains a set of itself with a custom comparer--circular reference

Tags: c++, templates, set

Here's the goal (code simplified, of course):

```
#include <set>

struct Node
{
   int Value;
   std::set<Node*, CompareNodes> Children;
};

struct CompareNodes
{
   bool operator()(const Node* l, const Node* r)
   {
      return l->Value < r->Value;
   }
};
```

But this doesn't compile; the type `CompareNodes` is unknown when it's encountered inside of `Node`. I could reverse the order, but then I have the opposite problem--`Node` would be unknown when it was encountered inside of `CompareNodes`. Forward declaration doesn't help in either case because each type uses the other in a way that requires its full definition. An ugly workaround is this:

```
#include <set>

template<typename T>
struct CompareNodes
{
   bool operator()(const T* l, const T* r)
   {
      return l->Value < r->Value;
   }
};

struct Node
{
   int Value;
   std::set<Node*, CompareNodes<Node>> Children;
};
```

Is there a better way? Bonus points if the answer will work even when `Node` is an inner class.

Comment: You can't make standard library containers of incomplete types anyway, at least not portably.

Comment: In plain English, you can't have a class that contains a set of itself.

Comment: @juanchopanza Hm. It may not be portable, but my compiler allows it. Does it still count as an incomplete type if I change it to `std::set<Node*>`?

Comment: that would be fine. Or use the `boost::set` from the boost.container library.

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested class as a comparator:

```
#include <set>

struct Node
{
   struct CompareNodes
   {
      bool operator()(const Node& l, const Node& r)
      {
         return l.Value < r.Value;
      }
   };

   int Value;
   std::set<Node, CompareNodes> Children;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Forward declaration doesn't help in either case

Not quite true. Forward declaration will work just fine:

```
#include <set>

struct Node;

struct CompareNodes
{
    bool operator()(const Node& l, const Node& r);
};

struct Node
{
   int Value;
   std::set<Node, CompareNodes> Children;
};

bool CompareNodes::operator()(const Node& l, const Node& r)
{
    return l.Value < r.Value;
}
```

If the `operator()` member function needs to be declared in a header file, it will be necessary to stick an `inline` keyword to it.

Comment: I believe `sts::set<Node,CompareNodes>` requires `Node` to be a complete type?  Or did that change recently?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could make use of templates to delay completeness check until usage?

```
#include <set>

struct CompareNodes;

template <class Cmp = CompareNodes>
struct Node
{
   int Value;
   std::set<Node*, Cmp> Children;
};

struct CompareNodes
{
   bool operator()(const Node<>* l, const Node<>* r)
   {
      return l->Value < r->Value;
   }
};

int main() {
    Node<> n;
}
```